# How to use select with if condition with different tables in oracle rather than writing a function or stored procedure?

Tags: oracle

My requirement is to get a report from a complex query using a if sentence.

If a `flag=0` I must perform  set of select statements, if the `flag = 1` I must perform another set of select statements from another table,

Is there any way I can achieve this in a query rather than writing a function or stored procedure?

Eg:
In SQL I do this

```
if flag = 0  
      select var1, vari2 from table1  
else  
      select var1, vari2, var3, vari4 from table2
```

Is this possible ??

Comment: If you want to build a plain SQL returning a variable number of columns, you can not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `if` in SQL - there is the `case` expression, but it is not quite the same thing.

If you have two tables, `t1` and `t2`, and `flag` is in a scalar table `t3` ("scalar" means exactly one column, `flag`, and with exactly one row, with the value either `0` or `1`), you can do what you want but only if `t1` and `t2` have the same number of columns, with the same data types (and, although not required by syntax, this would only make sense if the columns in `t1` and `t2` have the same business meaning). Or, at least, if you plan to select only some columns from `t1` or from `t2`, the columns you want to select from either table should be equal in number, have the same data type, and preferably the same business meaning.

For example: `t1` and `t2` may be employee tables, perhaps for two companies that just merged. If they both include `first_name, last_name, date_of_birth` and you just want to select these three columns from either `t1` or `t2` based on the `flag` value (even if `t1` has other columns, not present in `t2`), you can do it. Same if `t1` or `t2` or both is not a single table, but the result of a more complicated query. The principle is the same.

The way you can do it is with a `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, ...
from   t1 cross join t3
where  t3.flag = 0
UNION ALL
select t2.col1, t2.col2, ...
from   t2 cross join t3
where  t3.flag = 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks, But, the union all only works with the same number of columns, in my case I have two columns in the first query and four columns in the second query.

Comment: @EdgarConrado - Then it's not something you can do in SQL. You are probably going to do this in PL/SQL or in Java or C# or whatever.